# Determining when an Interrupt Routine will end for Gameboy GB Emulation

Tags: c, assembly, emulation, gameboy

So for context I would like to let you know what I understand so far:

- Interupt Handling is called after an instruction execution and Interrupt Master Enable flag is set.
- Interupt Handling is comprised of serveral "interrupt routines" (for gameboy, it has Vblank, LCD stat, timer, joypad, and serial).
- CPU needs to handle each interupt depending on values set on IE flag and IF flag.
- Interupt routines has priorities (not really related to my question).
- Interrupt routines **must have** start and end

So looking into interupt routines, it starts with pushing registers values that should be retained after the routine ends into the stack pointer. Now it always has reti instruction which I think is **always** the end of an interupt routine which should pop the address of the next instruction before the interupt was handled.

I would like to know if:

- is it a "standard" that reti instruction should appear only **once** each interupt routine and appears **only** at the end? because that's the only way I could determine if I would end reading further instruction,
- it uses reti instead of ret because we want to assert that ime flag is still enabled and thus can continue checking if any other interupt needs to be served,
- before the start of an interupt handling, I need to explicitly push the address of the next instruction into the stack pointer, since there is no assembly instruction indicating of pushing it before the start of interupt handling. This is for reti intruction btw at the end of an interupt.

EDIT:

So to give more context about my problem I decided to post my instruction cycle code.

in CPU.c

```
#include "InteruptHandler.c"
void main(){
    while(){ //No proper argument yet. for fetch-decode-execute cycle
    opcode = fetchInstruction();
    decodeandExecuteInstruction(opcode); //Lets say an instruction is executed and it enabled the IME_flag. that is IME_flag = ENABLED

    //Check if ime_flag is enabled. processInterupt if true.
    isInteruptEnabled() ? processInterupts(): 0; //This would fall true.
    }
}
```

In InteruptHandler.c

```
processInterupts(){

    opcode;
    bitmask = 0x01;

    //Check each bit for interupt. Bitmask will go 0x00 if the value 0x80 is shifted by 1
    for(; bitmask ; bitmask = bitmask << 1){

        //CHeck if IE and IF flag for corresponding interupt is set. process interupt if set
        IE_flag & bitmask ? (IF_flag & bitmask ? determineInterupt(bitmask) : 0) : 0; 
    }
}

determineInterupt(bitmask){

    //push the next instruction address to stack pointer
    push(PC);

    //Set PC into corresponding interupt address

//code below is my problem. I stumbled upon how would I end this function and I came up to determining when an interupt routine ends. 
//I came up with the reti function. 
//But after realizing that I already set the PC somewhere above this code, I just need to discard this code and let the main function do its instruction cycling. 
//Thanks to @duskwuff for pointing that out. 
//I just added some code to end the bitmask checking when it sees 1 interupt request and is most priotiry. 
//Also thanks to @Ped7g for giving me more information about the complexity of interupt handling. I'm not yet seeing where I should implement those. There are still so many thing to implement and yet to know when this excatly can happen.
//My question has been answered nevertheless, which is to end a function code blocks that I discarded at the end :)

//process the corresponding interupt
    do{
        opcode = fetchInstruction();
        decodeandexecuteInstruction(opcode);
    }while (opcode != RETI)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Interrupt routines must have start and end

This is not true. You should not make any assumptions about the layout of code in memory -- just run the instructions you encounter.

Under some circumstances, it's possible for an interrupt service routine to reenable interrupts *before* returning to allow another interrupt to be serviced at the same time. Your design should allow for this.

> it uses reti instead of ret because we want to assert that ime flag is still enabled and thus can continue checking if any other interupt needs to be served,

No. The RETI instruction reenables interrupts while returning -- it's effectively a combination of EI and RET. There is no assertion involved.

Comment: > This is not true. You should not make any assumptions about the layout of code in memory -- just run the instructions you encounter.  
-Suppose there has multiple intrupt requests- that is, respectve IF flags are set - how would the cpu process the other ones if it doesnt know when the current intrupt is finished? I believe that's the purpose of the reti instruction to inform the CPU that the intrupt has finished and it sets the PC register to point to the last instruction. But the cpu wouldnt let the next instruction to be excuted yet because there are remaining intrupts to be processed.

Comment: @butchtiki do the same a *real* CPU does: Use an interrupt flag determining whether the CPU is in interrupt mode (cleared by a *return from interrupt* instruction) and check for pending interrupt conditions before every instruction, except when the CPU is in interrupt mode.

Comment: > (cleared by a return from interrupt instruction - Do you mean the ime flag. But I'm not sure since you just said that it is clear by a return from an interupt instruction. But what I understand yet is after an interupt routine, it re-enables the ime flag via reti instruction. CPU will check if this is the last interupt that is processed. If true, I -as the CPU- would explicitly disables the ime flag without requiring to read assembly instruction. This would prevent me-the cpu- from processing interupts every other execution of subsequent instruction in normal mode (not processing interupt).

Comment: @butchtiki does GB actually queue interrupts? I thought they just get lost, in case the interrupts are disabled at the moment of raising interrupt request. (this is just pure guess, I didn't truly study GB blueprints/docs, I'm just guessing from ZX experience, as it has similar CPU, and I'm not aware of Z80 storing any complex state anywhere (except the shadow registers being actually quite complex storage for that era ... and those are not present on GB modified CPU).

Comment: @Ped7g It doesnt queue interupts once the ime flag is disabled. But once the ime flag is enabled, all interupt requests at that moment (that is IF register) should be handled provided that its corresponding flag in IE register is enabled. At least that's how my understanding so far.

Comment: @butchtiki .... hmm.. doesn't it service just the most prioritized one, others being lost? How can it recall which requests were on when it started processing the first one? (still consider this as chit-chat with somebody who doesn't know any fact about GB, so I'm sorry if this is wasting your time, then again sometimes these dumb questions help the OP to resolve it on his own, right? At least that's how it works for me sometimes  :) )

Comment: @butchtiki *"... if it doesnt know when the current intrupt is finished?"* it doesn't care. If there's IRQ, and interrupts are enabled, then it picks the one with most priority and switch execution to it. If it is re-entrant-like written, with a bug, it will simply crash when the stack memory gets exhausted, otherwise re-entrant Int-handler will return from the last one into previous one and finish that, as ordinary code, returning once more into code. If there's IRQ and interrupts are disabled, then it throws it away (I think, at least on ZX). There's no "interrupt" mode on Z80, just EI/DI.

Comment: Well I guess something I just read about makes me realize it doesnt actually queue the interupts even when the ime flag is enabled just process the one that is the highest priority and is requesting an interupt, all other interupts are discarded. Cant yet visualize what you just said on _ If it is re-entrant-like written, with a bug, it will simply crash when the stack memory gets exhausted, otherwise re-entrant Int-handler will return from the last one into previous one and finish that, as ordinary code, returning once more into code._ But I'm gonna consider this.

Comment: @butchtiki I mean upon entering handler, the return address and flags are pushed onto the stack (or maybe just return address, my Z80 is very rusty, spend many years on x86 after). So every new IRQ calling handler will push return address to the currently interrupted code. Then in handler you are in `DI` => no interrupt possible. But if you do intentional `EI` to make it re-entrant (or just other-IRQ-friendly), and by bug in code you never reach `RET`, your return address stays on the stack forever and it will not return into the original code, just your buggy handler will pile up recursively.

Comment: And if the handlers are correct, then the later handler interrupting your previous `EI`-like handler will return into your handler after dealing with his IRQ, and the first handler will finish its job, and return to original code.. meanwhile if the same IRQ is posted, that handler interrupts itself (re-entry), thus if such case is possible (really slow and long running handler), it needs its own re-entry logic to lock/unlock the long taking parts to run just one of them at time, and finish the re-entry later requests quickly just by return (if it doesn't have such logic, it may pile up).

Comment: All of that looks to CPU basically as ordinary machine code, the only "interrupt" thing about it is the IME flag modification by `DI`/`EI`/`RETI` and handling the interrupt requests signals, but executing the very first instruction of the interrupt handler is already for CPU just like any other instruction AFAIK (again I warn you I didn't study particular GB CPU docs, and as they have probably some graphics/sounds chips specialities, there may be some extra exceptions ... I'm describing you ordinary 8/16-bit era CPU soft (maskable) interrupts logic, special HW may have extras).